# Python ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I get the message ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension. Here is the code. Where is the mistake?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 200);
y = 4* signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 4 * k, 0.5)* signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 4 * k, 0.5);

plt.stem(x, y, use_line_collection=True);
plt.show();
```

Comment: Your `k` is not defined. I tried to use `k=1` but then got another kind of error. I guess you are using wrong value of `k`. I have tried to replace `k` with `x` and it finally works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the length of `x` and `y` arrays must be the same for `stem()`, I doubt you have a `k` (didn't show in your code snippet) resulting in a different dimension for `y`

You can check if your `len(y)` equals to 200, it should work when it's 200 (same as `x`). As an example, the below would work

```
x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 200)  # length = 200
k = np.arange(0, 200)  # length = 200
y = 4* signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 4 * k, 0.5)* signal.sawtooth(2 * np.pi * 4 * k, 0.5)
plt.stem(x, y, use_line_collection=True)
```